# Start multiple resque workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Tried `COUNT=5 QUEUE=* rake resque:workers` but would only spawn 1 worker.  Is it required to use God for multiple workers?

The instructions on the link did work
http://ephemera.karmi.cz/post/845791249/rake-task-to-launch-multiple-resque-workers-in

Comment: How do you know it is only spinning up 1?  Are you using resque-web to verify?  COUNT always works for me.

Comment: Yes, I look at resque-web and see 0 for 0 workers all though when I go to the "Workers" tab I see `all workers` instead of individual instances.  Is this how it works?

Comment: Took a little while before the workers show up in resque-web but that command works for me.